# load balance with spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm unable to figure from `spring-cloud-gateway` docs how to configure a load balancer. Some basic facts about my approach.

1. Not Using eureka or ribbon. But planning to use ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter
2. Using a combination of java-dsl and yaml filters

What I need help with is how to configure a `lb://` scheme after a gateway filter(1st filter), so I can route request to multiple backend servers.

My 1st filter is:

```
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
builder.routes().route("rewrite_response_obj", r -> r
                        .asyncPredicate(serverWebExchange -> {
                            return Mono.just(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().contains("mis2"));
                        })
                        .filters(f -> {
                                    return f.prefixPath("/")
                                            .modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                                    (exchange, s) -> Mono.just("2222222"));
                                }
                        )
                        .uri("lb://target-lb")) // How to configure target-lb 
                .build();
}
```

Spring docs have a lot of reference to use `lb://xyz` but I cant find where they have configured it?

I tried:

```
spring:
  cloud:
      loadbalancer:
        ribbon:
          enabled: false
        instances:
          - name: target-lb
            servers: http://localhost:8800
```

But it says:

> 2021-03-03 18:49:42.507  WARN 55243 --- [ctor-http-nio-3]
> o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for
> service: target-lb

Libs in my class-path:

```
spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer
spring-cloud-starter-gateway
```

Comment: Use simple discovery client. Sample here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/e1c570af07839951276ec6df2c0ac90588fcc151/spring-cloud-commons/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientTests.java#L42-L45

Open issue here to document: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/821

Comment: @spencergibb
Got a simple.discovery.client configured. thanks. How can I weighted load balance it? Also can I dynamically add/remove backend instances to this client without using spring-config server?

Comment: Were working on a weighted spring cloud load balancer implementation. Updating servers dynamically without a service registry or dynamic config? Try updating the file and posting to `/actuator/refresh`.

Comment: @spencergibb, about refreshing routes wihout registry. Used a [at]PropertySource external .properties, added an instance with "spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.misc-service1[2].uri=http://localhost:8802" then made a "/actuator/gateway/refresh" and "/actuator/refresh" which returned 200. Still this new address with 8802 wasnt added. Any heads up?

Comment: @PropertySource is not picked up be refresh. Only spring boot configuration properties

Comment: @spencergibb, ok will use that. WIll that refresh the SimpleDiscoveryClient instances, right?

Comment: @spencergibb, it did. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @spencergibb, one more thing, please. Is there a way for simple discovery client to provide only healty URLs.  I find something in spring-loud-lb docs that I can use HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier but I'm unable to find any eample that explains how.